# ARM64 thread related changes

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, arm64, smartfoxserver

Is there any changes in arm64 architecture thread handling mechanism? That mean any limit to sleep/wakeup calls or minimum sleep time.

Because I got an issue when integrating smartfox C++ API, the iOS kills one of my main communication thread without providing any notification. I not sure about the exact scenario, but this cause a deadlock condition in my application.

This issue is not occurring  when I disable arm64 architecture. Please help.

Thanks,

Akhil

Comment: Seems to me that this would be more of an iOS question than an ARM64 architecture question.

Comment: But there is no issue when I disabled arm64 architecture.

Comment: I'd suspect a general 32-bit to 64-bit porting issue rather than anything specific to ARM64: http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0004/.  But then again I don't' know anything about iOS or smartfox, so I could be plain wrong.

Comment: Thread handling is a property of the OS, not the architecture. This is about iOS.